# Yandex frequently replaces page names with ampersands

Tags: web-crawlers, crawl-errors, yandex

The Yandex spider is a frequent visitor to one of the sites I manage. On occasion it replaces the page name with two ampersands and a space. So if the page is:

```
/mypage.aspx?param=value
```

then it will try and crawl it as:

```
/&& ?param=value
```

Any idea why it is doing this?

EDIT:
If I remember correctly the IP that this *mistake* is coming from is based in California and not Russia. I believe that they crawl US sites from a US based IP address. Not sure if that helps.

More information about the request:

```
IP: 199.21.99.82
City: Palo Alto
State: California
Country: United States
ISP: Yandex Inc.
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; YandexBot/3.0; +http://yandex.com/bots)
```

Answer (score 1):

There could only be two explanations for this behavior:

1. The crawler found a link to that malformed URL, either on your site or on some other site.
2. The Yandex crawler has a bug.

If you aren't seeing that URL crawled by other bots or visited by real users, then I suspect it is a bug with the Yandex crawler.  As for why Yandex would have that particular bug, I can't say.  There is no valid reason for any user agent to make that type of substitution in a URL.

Answer (score -1):

Its probably mis-translating your URL, may be if your URL was more simplified such as mypage.com/page-two

Comment: Do you have any backing information for this? There's absolutely nothing unusual about that example. The Yandex engineers would have to be pretty incompetent to screw it up.

Comment: http://help.yandex.com/webmaster/?id=1113851 It provides details as to what Yandex will and will not except as URL strings.

Comment: I agree with Su'. Also that links to their robot guidelines/instructions and has nothing to do with this. The link in the example is normal and valid. Yandex should not have problems with it.